# ssTTsSTtRrriinInnnnNNNIiinngg

Tags: code-golf, string, random

### Challenge

For each character of the string except for the last one, do the following:

- Output the current character.
- Followed by randomly outputting from the following list a random number of times between 1 - 5 (inclusive):

  - The current character
  - The next character of the string
  - The switchcase version of the character that you are currently on
  - The switchcase version of the next character of the string.

### Test Cases

`String` --> `SSSTSStrTrIiinIIngn`

`, . , . , . Hello world!` --> `,,,  ..    , ,,    ....    , ,   .. .. .   HHH HHEeelLlLllooO   wwOworOOrrrRllDd!!D`

`Programming Puzzles and Code Golf` --> `PrPPrRrOooooogggRgGraAraaaMMMmmmimMIiininGGgG  PPPPuZzZZzZzzZzllLLEEeEsEsssS  a aANnNddD C  COCoooOOdeDe   E GGGoOllFFf`

### Notes

- You only need to apply the switchcase version of a character if the character is part of the alphabet (A-Z and a-z).
- Your random function does not need to be uniform but it still needs to have a chance of returning any element in the list given.
- You are allowed to use any standard I/O format.
- You may assume that the length of the input is greater than or equal to two.
- You may assume that the input only consists of ASCII characters.
- The title is not a test case (it is unintentional if it is a valid test case).
- Switchcase means to turn the char to lowercase if it is uppercase and to turn it to uppercase if it is lowercase.

Comment: In addition to '... does not need to be uniform', I think you probably want to specify that given some input, all finite legal outputs should in principle be possible to generate (otherwise, my non-uniform random integer in [1,2,3,4,5] is always going to be 2, and I'll just output the original string).

Comment: @ChasBrown Yeah, I'll edit the question

Comment: What options do we have as source of randomness, can we use the input string?

Comment: I find the specification confusing. Can you be more explicit? For example, work out how `String` produces `SSSTSStrTrIiinIIngn`

Comment: @LuisMendo I'm not OP, but I think: `[S]SSTSS [t]rT, [r]I, [i]inII, [n]gn`, where the characters between the blocks are the first bullet points ("_Output the current character_"), and the other characters are 1-5 times randomly one of the four choices for that character. But I agree, some more explicit explanations would be appropriate. Apart from the test case it wasn't particularly clear we have to pick a random choice 1-5 times. Instead of picking a random choice repeated 1-5 times (as the Gaia answer currently does).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thanks, Your explanation fits the example, and is clear. The OP should  confirm and edit that into the text

Comment: It took me several minutes to figure out what you meant by "switchcase version". Google didn't turn up anything. Might help to show an example on the line.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I will change "1 and 5" to "1 - 5"

Comment: @LuisMendo What are you confused about? Do you have any suggestion on how to be more explicit?

Comment: I think it's clear now. I removed my vote to close

Answer (score 6):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 25 bytes

```
ṇ\+†ṅ\⟨)₌¤:~+4ṛ⟨ṛ₌¤⟩ₓ\⟩¦$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz//@HO9hjtRw0LHu5sjXk0f4Xmo6aeQ0us6rRNHu6cDeSDSJDIo/krHzVNBqpYeWiZyv//wSVFmXnpAA)

*Thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen) for pointing out 2 bugs!*

```
ṇ\				| delete the last character from the input
  +†				| push the input again and concatenate together, so for instance
				| 'abc' 'bc' becomes ['ab' 'bc' 'c']
    ṅ\				| delete the last element
       ⟨       		⟩¦	| for each of the elements, do:
	)₌			| take the first character and push again
	  ¤			| swap
	   :			| dup
	    ~			| swap case
	     +			| concatenate strings
	      4ṛ		| select a random integer from [1..5]
	        ⟨    ⟩ₓ		| and repeat that many times
		 ṛ₌¤		| select a random character from the string
		      \ 	| clean up stack
			   $	| convert to string
```

Note that `4ṛ` is because `ṛ` is implemented for an integer `z` as python's `random.randint(1,z+1)`, which returns an integer `N` such that `1<=N<=z+1`.

Comment: Are you sure the run-length encode is correct here? If I understand the challenge correctly: the four options should be chosen 1-5 times randomly, instead of choosing one of the four randomly, repeated 1-5 times. The first example output `SSSTSStrTrIiinIIngn` (`[SSSTSS, trT, rI, iinII, ngn]`) seems to reflect this, and currently isn't a possible output in your program (I think).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I interpreted "output from the list a random number of times" to mean run-length decode, but you're right, the test cases do seem to indicate the other interpretation; I think it should be pretty easy to fix

Comment: `5ṛ` can result in `6` for some reason [Try it online](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz/3/ThztmFo8SIIv7/BwA)? PS: Isn't there an integer to ranged list, or ranged for-loop in Gaia?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen dang, Business Cat really needs to fix off-by-one errors...I really thought there was a `for` type construct, but I'm pretty sure it's `ₓ` which isn't even documented on the wiki page.

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (dzaima/APL)](https://github.com/dzaima/APL), 23 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

Anonymous tacit prefix function.

```apl
∊2(⊣,{?4⍴⍨?5}⊇,,-⍤,)/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pSszMTfz/P@1R24RHHV1GGo@6FutU25s86t3yqHeFvWnto652HR3dR71LdDT1/z/qmwpUl6YeXFKUmZeuzgXj6yjoKcCwR2pOTr5CeX5RTooiQkVAUX56UWJuLlCbQkBpVVVOarFCYl6KgnN@SqqCe35Omvp/AA)

`2(`…`)/` apply the following infix tacit function between each character pair:

`-` the switchcase
 `⍤` of
 `,` the concatenation of the pair

`,,` prepend the concatenation of the pair to that

`{`…`}⊇` pick the following elements from that:

`?5` random number in range 1…5

`4⍴⍨` that many fours

`?` random indices for those

`∊` **ϵ**nlist (flatten)

Answer (score 3):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 121 bytes

*-20 bytes thanks to Nahuel*

*-9 bytes thanks to roblogic*

```bash
for((i=0;i<${#1};i++)){
s=${1:i:1}
m=${1:i:2}
m=${m,,}${m^^}
for((t=0;t++<RANDOM%6;)){
s+=${m:RANDOM%4:1}
}
printf "$s"
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifpqFZ/T8tv0hDI9PWwDrTRqVa2bDWOlNbW1OzmqvYVqXa0CrTyrCWKxfKNIIwc3V0aoFkXFwtF1hzCVBziba2TZCjn4u/r6qZNVi7NkilFVTMBGRMLVdBUWZeSZqCkkqxElft/1ourjQF9cS8/JKM1CKFktTiEgU9HYXC8tSikkr1/wA)

### Original answer

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 150 bytes

Have done very little golf bashing and trying to improve my bash, so any comments welcome.

```bash
for((i=0;i<${#1}-1;i++));do
c=${1:$i:1}
n=${1:$((i+1)):1}
a=($n ${c,} ${c^} ${n,} ${n^})
shuf -e ${a[@]} -n "$(shuf -i 1-5 -n 1)"|xargs printf %s
done
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYpBCsIwEEX3OcWgETLUgLNw01rwDi7FQmybNpupNBWEmLPHxm4e7z/@0/gxWYUh2WlWytWnyl1k2FPUVLmiQKy6SbS1DFRKV1IUvPn6LQgxF1MrySBDe4yZTSb/nZuIwo9vC7pfp7lfHxE0w06qrTogfc6FcPf9mHnw8JodLxYOXnQT9ykKYeG2rHFIPw)

Code is straightforward loop through chars setting current `c` and next `n` character, then creating an array of the 4 possibilities, repeating one of them so there's exactly 5.  Next we shuffle that array, and then choose n elements from it, where n itself is random between 1 and 5.

Comment: seems it's missing `printf %s "$c"`

Comment: `do` and `done` can be replaced with undocumented `{` and `}`

Comment: [with some changes](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifpqFZ/T8tv0hDI9PWwDrTRqVa2bBW19A6U1tbU9O6mqvYVqXa0CrTyrCWKxfKNIIwc3V0aoFkXFwtF1h/CVB/iY1tkKOfi7@vqql1CcwEbZBiK6i4CcikWq6Cosy8kjQF1WIFJZViJa7a/7VcXGkKwSVA4fT/AA)

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul tyvm.  nice improvements and nice catch -- i'd somehow missed the requirement always to output the current char.

Comment: [optimising](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifpqFZ/T8tv0hDI9PWwDrTRqVa2bDWOlNbW1OzmqvYVqXa0CrTyrCWKxfKNIIwc3V0aoFkXFwtF1hzCVBziba2TZCjn4u/r6qZNVi7NkilFVTMBGRMLVdBUWZeSZqCkkqxElft/1ourjQF9cS8/JKM1CKFktTiEgU9HYXC8tSikkr1/wA) the `for` loops to save 9 bytes :)

Comment: @roblogic that's clever.  tyvm.

Comment: The 121-byte solution is a bit fragile/buggy, here's a more robust (133-byte) version that should handle *all* printable ASCII, [tio.run](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/Py2/SEPDOtNGpVrZsNY6U1tbU7NaodhWSaXa0CrTyrBWyToXxjGCcXJ1dGqBZFxcrRIXRH@JTZCjn4u/r6qpdQnEiAptsEorqLgJ2KhartTkjHwF3TwFJZVilQolrhJb6wpb69r////rxtvWanuk5uTkK7gmFpVk5GTmpRcrqipYaQIA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 60 bytes

```perl6
{S:g{.)>(.)}=$/~[~] roll ^5 .roll+1,$/.lc,$/.uc,$0.lc,$0.uc}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYvBCoJAGITvPcUkEi7JWoc6JHbpUEehYxRIrhL8uvJvEir66ptG0WE@PoaZSjFtbdFgkSGC7c67vJNi70nRR24wXIYrWBPhtoGcZLn23UDSfWI9cvXx1ei9NUmDzHPMkx9l7ohw9i18SPxyUkQaL82Uzv8TQzVXIrQx65yTohj/iOu2JWWQlCkOOlU4asre)

The lowercase/uppercase part is kinda annoying.

Comment: I don't know Perl, so I'm probably saying something stupid here. But is it somehow possible to concat the `$/` and `$0` together and use `.lc` on that string, and then create a copy of that string and use `.uc`, and concat those two together? Not sure if that's even possible, or shorter than your current `$/.lc,$/.uc,$0.lc,$0.uc`, but it would mean you'd use `$/`, `$0`, `.lc`, and `.uc` once each.

Comment: Alas, `(.lc~.uc for $0~$/).comb` is longer. Perl 6 really wants to distinguish strings and lists, so `"abc"[0] eq "abc"` (it pretends to be a single-item list).

Comment: You can do it by slipping and an anonymous function applied to a list: `{.lc,|.uc}($/,|$0)` for -5 bytes, and just use the list of matches `{.lc,|.uc}(@$/)` for -8 bytes. https://tio.run/##RYvBCoJAFEX3fcVNJBySkRa1UIygRS2FllEgOkrwdORNEmr661NB0eLC4XBuo5g2tuqwKBDDDqewHKTYelKMsRtM5@kC1kS4riE/sFz5g6TMf8o2G72dG4jRmrRD4Tnmzre6dEQ0@wofEr8dFZHGQzPl839iqOVGRDZhXXJaVe8/krbvSRmkdY69zhUOmooX

Comment: @PhilH No that doesn't work. Those solutions only capitalise [one of the letters each](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwvzrYKr1aT9NOQ0@z1lZFvy66LlahKD8nRyHOVEEPxNA21KnWy0nWqdErTa7VcFDR16z9z6Veklpcol5Xpw/RqW/NVZxYqQBWB1amoq9To2KgiS4M0m39P6AoP70oMTc3My9dIaC0qiontVghMS9FwTk/JVXBPT8nDQA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
;Œsṗ5X¤XṭṖµƝ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASYA2f9qZWxsef//O8WSc@G5lzVYwqRY4bmt4bmWwrXGnf///1N0cmluZw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 107 bytes

```python
f=lambda s:s and s[0]+''.join(sample((s[:2]+s[:2].swapcase())*5,randint(1,5)))+f(s[1:])
from random import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYs7CsMwEET7nEKddi1jYoMbQU6R0qhYx1aiYH3QCkJOr8hpZgbem/QtrximWu3tIL9uJFizoLAJXq5GSTm8owvA5NOxA/CiJ6P@OfCH0oN4B8Ru7nP7uFBg7GdEVLapozZ4sTl6ccJWzqeYS1dTbqawIO@lrafE@gM)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>18</s> 17 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ü)vyн5LΩFyD.š«Ω]J
```

Inspired by [*@Giuseppe*'s Gaia answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/182566/52210).
-1 byte thanks to *@Shaggy*.

[Try it online 10 times](https://tio.run/##ASsA1P9vc2FiaWX/VEb/w7wpdnnQvTVMzqlGeUQuxaHCq86pfX1K/yz/U3RyaW5n) or [verify all test cases 10 times](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9WGWpo4Bbx//AezbLKC3tNfc6tdKt00Tu68NDqcytra73@6/yPVgouKcrMS1fSUQAiPQUY9kjNyclXKM8vyklRBMkFFOWnFyXm5gKVKgSUVlXlpBYrJOalKDjnp6QquOfnpIEUgTUpxQIA).

**Explanation:**

```python
ü)             # Create all pairs of the (implicit) input
               #  i.e. "Hello" → [["H","e"],["e","l"],["l","l"],["l","o"]]
  v            # Loop over each these pairs `y`:
   yн          #  Push the first character of pair `y`
   5LΩ         #  Get a random integer in the range [1,5]
      F        #  Inner loop that many times:
       y       #   Push pair `y`
        D.š«   #   Duplicate it, swap the cases of the letters, and merge it with `y`
            Ω  #   Then pop and push a random character from this list of four
  ]J           # After both loops: join the entire stack together to a single string
               # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Comment: I don't know 05AB1E but, instead of `INè`, could you save anything by pushing the first character of `y`?

Comment: @Shaggy Yes, I indeed can.. Thanks! Maybe I should stop golfing for today, I'm a mess, lol..

Comment: ***You're*** a mess? `¨vNUy5LΩFy¹X>è«D.š«Ω?`

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Although a pretty original approach, I'm afraid it doesn't do the first bullet point of the challenge ("_Output the current character._"), since the result can start with `t`, `T`, or `s` for input `"String"` in your program, while it's supposed to always start with the `S`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 27 bytes

```
ＦＬθ«Ｆ∧ι⊕‽⁵‽⭆✂θ⊖ι⊕ι¹⁺↥λ↧λ§θι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY3LCsIwEEXX7VdkOYG6cOHKVcFNoUJp8QNCMraBdNKm8QHit8fEouKFWZwDc68chJNWmBDO1jGokXo/wMw5e@TZW5WkQBesIulwRPKooBWk7Ag7HsMap8l/VOcj9UcxQWe0RJgLdsDfo@b/RYm38RpzWeA0TeikWBBMVLW9fSlln2frUukrUnhP1TrpZwjrathczQs) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
ＦＬθ«
```

Loop over all of the indices of the input string.

```
Ｆ∧ι⊕‽⁵
```

Except for the first index, loop over a random number from 1 to 5 inclusive...

```
‽⭆✂θ⊖ι⊕ι¹⁺↥λ↧λ
```

... extract the previous and next characters from the string, take the upper and lower case versions, and pick a random character of the four.

```
§θι
```

Print the character at the current index.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 14 bytes

```
;;;Œs$Xɗ¥5X¤¡Ɲ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AT8AwP9qZWxsef//Ozs7xZJzJFjJl8KlNVjCpMKhxp3///9Qcm9ncmFtbWluZyBQdXp6bGVzIGFuZCBDb2RlIEdvbGY)

#### Explanation

```
             Ɲ | For each overlapping pair of letters
;              | Join the first letter to...
         5X¤¡  | Between 1 and 5 repetitions of...
      Xɗ¥      | A randomly selected character from...
 ;;Œs$         | A list of the two letters and the swapped case versions of both
```

Answer (score 1):

## perl 5 (`-p`), 77 bytes

```
s/(.)(?=(.))/$x=$1;'$x.=substr"\U$1$2\L$1$2",4*rand,1;'x(1+5*rand)/gee;s/.$//
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YX0NPU8PeFkhq6qtU2KoYWqurVOjZFpcmFZcUKcWEqhiqGMX4gEglHROtosS8FB2gkgoNQ21TME9TPz011bpYX09FX////@CSosy8dC58VEBRfnpRYm4ukK0QUFpVlZNarAA0R8E5PyVVwT0/J22wqPiXX1CSmZ9X/F@3AAA)

Comment: You can save 4 bytes by using `$&` instead of `$1`, and `chop` + `-l` instead of `s/.$//`

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-P`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 14 bytes

```
äÈ+Zu pv ö5ö Ä
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVA&code=5MgrWnUgcHYg9jX2IMQ&input=IlN0cmluZyI)

```
äÈ+Zu pv ö5ö Ä     :Implicit input of string
ä                  :Take each consectutive pair of characters
 È                 :Pass them through the following function as Z
  +                :  Append to the first character of the pair
   Zu              :    Uppercase Z
      p            :    Append
       v           :      Lowercase
         ö         :    Get X random characters, where X is
          5ö       :      Random number in the range [0,5)
             Ä     :      Plus 1
                   :Implicitly join and output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 167 bytes

```python
from random import*;c=choice
def f(s):
 i=0;r=""
 for i in range(len(s)-1):
  r+=s[i]
  for j in range(randrange(5)):r+=c([str.upper,str.lower])(c(s[i:i+2]))
 return r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY2xbsMwDER3fwXhSYrbIE3RxYGnDl2zGx4MmbJZ2KJAyyiSn3coBEgnHu4e7@ItTRw@990LLyB9GPTQElnS4eIaNzE5LAb04M1q6wKoOV2kKcsCPAsQUMhfI5oZgxLvHxkCqZq1pU5Vpn7/qbzwVF/W1oo5065JjluMKG9ZzfyH0lnjjDbUVJ07awsQTJtoyR6FQjLelMpSGEsNX9ZVeJR@WdSH63a/z7iC7sE3Dwg/PHul9wc)

Answer (score 1):

## C(GCC) <s>175</s> <s>162</s> 150 bytes

-12 bytes from LambdaBeta

-12 bytes from ceilingcat

```
f(s,S,i,r,a)char*s,*S,*i;{srand(time(0));for(i=S;s[1];++s)for(r=rand(*i++=*s)%5+1;r--;*i++=rand()&1&&a>96&a<123|a>64&a<91?a^32:a)a=s[~rand()&1];*i=0;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7BToQwFEX3fkVDAulrS0JhnKRTO34ES8TkDdKZLqimxdWIv44Fo7ubc@5N7lBeh2FdLY2iFU4EgTDcMLAoWCuY0/cY0L/R2U0jrQC0fQ/UmVbHTvaa8wgbCGYvMce5YRHyRy51KEu9g11BIYsCz@pY4JOsmy88Hw8pKvmMr019QkATu@@/ap@WptLL6vxMJnSeArk/ELI9I5dPa8fQKaV6nZilWTsH56@Z@DWw0Y9E5qTy@OIzQf7Nsv4A)

Comment: I don't think you need the `0` in the first line.

Comment: Also can save a lot of characters by taking the buffer `S` as a parameter and adding your variables to the argument list: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7BbsIwEETvfMUqFchrOxIBiuS4of@QHNsiLSGme8Ct7HAK@fbUoVVvo/dGo2nzS9tO09O5c@w7qKtA/ixw4UTUjWYdNGH7SUFGLRst2Q7x0ej52ok1onVfQXDVWCmiKtAqFXGQrFQl48MFqJfPqrAhz@3M61XxSgezX9FLsdne6bDfpWgSPG43JZWEBHNHxvJvcpRcre04se/hSuwFwrAAmF/B6eZcF96MMR82MSeypg/sL5n@NTjT70T6pJbx3Wca/s04/QA "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: @LambdaBeta turns out you are right about the `0`, which made it not worth it to have the `#define` anymore

Comment: [140 bytes](https://tio.run/##Pc5BCsIwEIXhvacIBUsmScEqLmoIHqLLWmGspg5olExdiV69thXdfv9bvCZrm6bvvWRTGjLRIDRnjIqNKo0i@@SI4Sg7up7kAsD6W5TkSstVXlutGUaIbhop0tophvla5zZmmZ1gSpDmaUqMl/sZJcIW96vlBgEdV@/foB72bmFfPYVOXJGCBPGcCTH@EYeH96dYFUVR28G8TMouUmgT8y0w6n2Qbkhz3oXEiH959R8 "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>154</s> <s>105</s> <s>103</s> <s>95</s> 87 bytes

<sup>-67 bytes thanks to mazzy who can't be stopped</sup>

```powershell
-join(($x=$args)|%{$_;$x[$i,++$i]*5|%{"$_"|% *wer;"$_"|% *per}|random -c(1..5|random)})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkmZb/V83Kz8zT0NDpcJWJbEovVizRrVaJd5apSJaJVNHW1slM1bLFCikpBKvVKOqoAXUaw1jF6QW1dYUJeal5Ocq6CZrGOrpmUK5mrWa/2u5uFSKS4oy89IVbBWUgiGs4vy8dCUuNZU0BQeIHJe6OrIyRydnBRdXNxQl/wE)

<s>Not a fantastic method but it works.</s> Now it's pretty good. Takes input via splatting

Comment: Oh, wow, thats a lot of bytes.

Comment: @mazzy Dang dog. I need to get into the habit of splatting all the time but didn't know you could hotswap the wildcard members like that.

Comment: I'm sorry [87 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkmZb/V83Kz8zT0NDpcJWJbEovVizRrVaJd5apSJaJVNHW1slM1bLFCikpBKvVKOqoAXUaw1jF6QW1dYUJeal5Ocq6CZrGOrpmUK5mrWa/2u5uFSKS4oy89IVbBWUgiGs4vy8dCUuNZU0BQeIHJe6OrIyRydnBRdXNxQl/wE "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-P`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), <s>43</s> 16 bytes

```
äÈ+(Zv +Zu)ö5ö Ä
```

Shortened by a lot now!

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVA&code=5MgrKFp2ICtadSn2NfYgxA&input=IlN0cmluZyI)

Comment: This seems to return the same result every time.

Comment: @Shaggy will fix. Also, `ä`'s description says it gives three arguments, with the last being `x+y`. But as you can see [here](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=5EBa&input=WyJTIiwidCIsInIiLCJpIiwibiIsImciXQ), it just returns 1. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), <s>236</s> <s>213</s> 209 bytes

```cs
a=>{int i=0,j;var m=new Random();var s="";var c = a.Select(x=>Char.IsLetter(x)?(char)(x^32):x).ToArray();for(;i<a.Length-1;i++)for(j=m.Next(1,5);j-->0;)s+=new[]{a[i],c[i],a[i+1],c[i+1]}[m.Next(0,3)];return s;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY5RS8MwFIXf9ytCn3JpG1qHL2apiCAIwwcVfCgdhCxdU9oEbjIXGfvtta2@3PPxwTlc5XPlzfRytmrnAxp7yv6iIq2YpKiuxgZiRJH1/FsiGYXVF/Iu7dGNFFblRZKsoIggkn3oQatAo6ieO4ns1e91CBpphEeqZgM0HrZ38BCBfbonRPkz77QOKTc7yfbankKXl9ykKSy2FyN70zHQMrsH3ud5VXDw6fJG3VxlbZpMLWemtFx5jlv9XyqyLTQcdTijJZ7fJr7ZfKEJmrY06fQwOHJxOBwTAD79Ag)

Comment: Does not work with non-alphanumeric characters. `char b=a[0]` -> `var b=a[0]`, extra space in declaration of `d` in for-loop

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala](https://scala-lang.org) 2.12.8, 214 bytes

Golfed version:

```scala
val r=scala.util.Random;println(readLine.toList.sliding(2).flatMap{case a :: b :: Nil=>(a +: (0 to r.nextInt(5)).map{_=>((c: Char)=>if(r.nextBoolean)c.toUpper else c.toLower)(if(r.nextBoolean)a else b)})}.mkString)
```

Golfed with newlines and indents:

```scala
val r=scala.util.Random
println(readLine.toList.sliding(2).flatMap{
  case a :: b :: Nil=>
    (a +: (0 to r.nextInt(5)).map{_=>
      ((c: Char)=>if(r.nextBoolean)c.toUpper else c.toLower)(if(r.nextBoolean)a else b)
    })
}.mkString)
```

Ungolfed:

```scala
import scala.io.StdIn
import scala.util.Random

def gobble(input: String): String = {
  input.toList.sliding(2).flatMap {
    case thisChar :: nextChar :: Nil =>
      val numberOfAdditions = Random.nextInt(5)
      (thisChar +: (0 to numberOfAdditions).map { _ =>
        val char = if(Random.nextBoolean) thisChar else nextChar
        val cc = if(Random.nextBoolean) char.toUpper else char.ToLower
        cc
      })
  }.mkString
}

println(gobble(StdIn.readLine()))
```

Comment: No way to turn `a :: b :: Nil` into `a::b::Nil`? Same for `a :+`, `a:+()` or `a.:+()` might work

Comment: @Ven `a::b::Nil` causes a compile error. `+:` is a method defined on the list, so it might save space by getting rid of the outer parens?

Comment: You only have only one elem here so it’s not autotupling anyway

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-n`, 61 bytes

```perl
s/.(?=(.))/print$&,map{(map{lc,uc}$&,$1)[rand 4]}0..rand 5/ge
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YX0/D3lZDT1NTv6AoM69ERU0nN7GgWgNE5CTrlCbXAkVUDDWjixLzUhRMYmsN9PTATFP99NT/1mA9CkoxeUr/g0u4gkuA3HQuHQU9BRj2SM3JyVcozy/KSVHkCijKTy9KzM0FKlIIKK2qykktVgCZ5Zyfkqrgnp@T9i@/oCQzP6/4v24eAA)

Answer (score 0):

## T-SQL query, 286 bytes

```sql
DECLARE @ char(999)='String'

SELECT @=stuff(@,n+2,0,s)FROM(SELECT
top 999*,substring(lower(c)+upper(c),abs(v%4)+1,1)s
FROM(SELECT*,number n,substring(@,number+1,2)c,cast(newid()as varbinary)v
FROM(values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5))F(h),spt_values)D
WHERE'P'=type and n<len(@)-1and h>v%3+2ORDER
BY-n)E
PRINT LEFT(@,len(@)-1)
```

**[Try it online](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1023387/ssttssttrrriininnnnnnniiinngg)** unfortunately the online version always show the same result for the same varchar, unlike MS SQL Server Management Studio

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 156 bytes

```cs
n=>{var k=new Random();int i=0;foreach(var j in n.Skip(1).Zip(n,(a,b)=>a+b))for(Write(j[1]),i=0;i++<k.Next(5);)Write(k.Next()%2<1?j.ToUpper():j.ToLower());}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY5BS8UwEITv/opQEHZpDVbwYpqIBw@CePApguIhjVvd9r1NSaNPEH97bXmeZphvGCZMJ2Hi@SpkjtLcXMvnjpJvt9RMObG8O9fZWaz7@fJJDVZor@69vMUdoGHJiu2p6WIiHz5grfSKRYneDDxCjfp5EanAVy1a58sWcSnDU@JM0L/Ur1itA1yWzaDv6DvDORo84P8Aj8@a@rLXD/FxHCkBXqz@Nu5Xj@Z3NkcdFIezhd7QlkKGYF0oi2Lh8x8)

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>110</s> 109 bytes

```c
i,p;g(char*_){for(i=rand(putchar(*_))%1024;p=_[i%2],putchar(i&2&&p>64&~-p%32<26?p^32:p),i/=4;);_[2]&&g(_+1);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZA9b8IwEIZ3fsU1UqIEAi0BMTSEDh3aoUOljoRGrm3Sk@zYtR0qgehfd00qpA433HPvvfdBpy2l3mOuyzaln8SMm@y0VybFypCOpbp3F5oGnMXzu2JZ6qrZYlzs8msJkyJJ9Ga1TH6mOl4U62L1oN8Xxb3OcrytlmVWNttilyRt2kzmWXn2kmCXYueA5sPI8SE7jQCGsYFiNS9xTUucTAYOoE3g@zSqo9jWEVQbqKMoP2xxl5WDoE3/JWExe9HWXTSQ8@js/ZsLHq3PYQbXeOZCKPhWRrAb/2pUa4iUQQSv/fEouIXwAHhUjMOTEnv/ogyXgNr2EpgSyoBFB0RylwNVneXUcdcbIAw1Wnox4gJD0XIWGoBjb6Vi4LjUoRk7igxZHw7uHQjyEeyBuz9rDpK0HQEi8Ksns18)

-1 thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/182559/ssttssttrrriininnnnnnniiinngg/182755?noredirect=1#comment439899_182755)

```c
i,p;g(char*_){
    for(i=rand(putchar(*_)) //print current char
         %1024;             // and get 10 random bits
        p=_[i%2],           //1st bit => current/next char
        putchar(i&2&&       //2nd bit => toggle case
            p>64&~-p%32<26  // if char-to-print is alphabetic
            ?p^32:p),
        i/=4;);             //discard two bits
    _[2]&&g(_+1);           //if next isn't last char, repeat with next char
}
```

---

The number of characters printed (per input character) is not uniformly random:

```c
1  if      i<   4 (  4/1024 = 1/256)
2  if   4<=i<  16 ( 12/1024 = 3/256)
3  if  16<=i<  64 ( 48/1024 = 3/ 64)
4  if  64<=i< 256 (192/1024 = 3/ 16)
5  if 256<=i<1024 (768/1024 = 3/  4)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Zsh, <s>113</s> 107 bytes

With a lot of help from `man zshexpn` and `man zshparam`. [Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/Lb9IQUPDOtNG2dA6U1tbU7M611al2tBKJdPKqNYayM61ygHiUi6owhKbIEc/F39fVVPrEpDyCm2g8txoqKBJbC1XanJGvgLQiOjM2FqVipiYZOsSW@sKW@va////68bb1mp7pObk5Cu4JhaVZORk5qUXK6oqWGkCAA)

- ***-6*** by me, tweaking

```js
for ((;i<#1;i++)){m=${1:$i:2};m=$m:l$m:u
for ((;t<RANDOM%5;t++))x+=${m[RANDOM%4]}
echo ${1[i]}$x\\c;t=;x=;}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 74 bytes

```ruby
gsub(/.(?=(.))/){([$&,$1,$&.swapcase,$1.swapcase]*5).sample(rand 1..5)*""}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpclm0km6BUuyCpaUlaboWN73Si0uTNPT1NOxtNfQ0NfU1qzWiVdR0VAx1VNT0issTC5ITi1OBXDg7VstUU684MbcgJ1WjKDEvRcFQT89UU0tJqRZiItTgBcuCS4oy89IhPAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 17 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
êß~Φ~a[├x◙w↓┬┬►{⌂
```

[Run and debug it at staxlang.xyz!](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=88e17ee87e615bc3780a7719c2c2107b7f&i=,+.+,+.+,+.+Hello+world%21%0AProgramming+Puzzles+and+Code+Golf&m=2)

#### Unpacked (20 bytes) and explanation:

```
2BFch]pc:~+5R|':$|'p
2B                      all size-2 subarrays
  F                     for each:
   ch]p                   print its first element
       c                  copy it on the stack
        :~                case-swap the copy
          +               concatenate
           5R|'           random integer 1-5, inclusive
               :$         Cartesian power
                 |'       random choice
                   p      print
```